# Running pig in local mode

Tags: hdfs, apache-pig

I am beginner to APACHE PIG and following is what i have a slight confusion

I am trying to run pig in local mode using 
pig -x local.

Now ia m trying the simple code

```
dividends = load 'NYSE_dividends' as (exchange, symbol, date, dividend);
grouping= group dividends by symbol;
avg= foreach grouped generate group, AVG(dividends.dividend);

store avg into 'average_dividend'.
```

A folder by the name average_dividend is formed on my machine.

Now as per the book if i want to run it in local mode I have to give the following syntax

```
pig_path/bin/pig -x local average_dividend.pig
```

But where is the file average_dividend.pig(like where it is formed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to run one of the [examples](https://github.com/alanfgates/programmingpig) of [Programming Pig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449302645).
First locate `average_dividend.pig` in the directory where you extracted the code.
Since you are working in *local mode* you have to set the path to `NYSE_dividends`,
e.g: `load '/home/user/programmingpig-master/data/NYSE_dividends'`,
Set the output directory (shouldn't exist) too where you want to save the result, e.g:
`store avg into '/home/user/output'`.

Then issue:

```
pig_path/bin/pig -x local -f average_dividend.pig
```

Comment: Hi  Lonard                                                                        Thanks for the reply but I haven't extracted the code ,instead I am writing the commands on grunt and then storing it on my HOME but i cannot find any .pig (extension file)..How to create the .pig file                              Thanks